# How to scan all O365 roles and users who has got which role Using MS Graph endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Anyone please help on how to get all the Office-365 roles and users for example who has got which roles (Azure, O365, SharePoint, etc other workloads …) Using MS Graph endpoint.

Unable able to find MSGraph endpoint to get the roles assigned to a user or a group of users.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to retrieve a list of the users that are assigned to the directory role. Similarly, List [directoryRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) can be used to get a list of the directory roles that are activated in the tenant.

Please refer to [Administrator roles for Microsoft 365 services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-m365-workload-docs#where-to-find-content) to determine the roles for which API content is available.

Comment: Hello @Aravind, please let me know if you need any additional assistance with this question. Also, please if the above answer helps you please accept the answer so that it can help others well.

Comment: Sure, i'll try and let you know